# p:dataList inside of p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using `<p:dataTable>` to show the values of my files. Inside of each file is a list of metadates. I want to show each metadate as an own column beside the other columns of the file. (I excluded the other columns to make the code more readable).

So, my problem is, that with the `<p:dataList>` it does not show the columns. The name of the meta is the same in every metadata, if someone believes this to be the problem.

I already tried to use `<p:dataTable>` instead of `<p:dataList>`, but as my customer originally wanted to have the metadata shown as own column this would not be my preferred way, but on the other hand it is working.

```html
<p:dataTable id="fileList" var="f" value="#{reader.files}" rendered="#{reader.showFileTable()}">
    <p:dataList value="#{f.meta}" var="meta1">
        <p:column>
           #{meta1.value}
        </p:column>
    </p:dataList>

    <p:column headerText="Metadaten">
        <p:dataTable value="#{f.meta}" var="meta">
            <p:column headerText="#{meta.name}">
                 #{meta.value}
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
     </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

I am really grateful for any help, how I could make the code work so that each `metadate` has it's own column in the `fileList-dataTable`.

**P.S:** I already tried `c:forEach` and `ui:repeat` which also didn't work.

**P.P.S:** I forgot to mention, that my customer sometimes don't want to see specific metadates, so it would be very nice when it is possible to do this with the suggested solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can build columns dynamically in primefaces by using the `<p:columns>` tag see the [vdl](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/columns.html)

check the [primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableDynamicColumns.jsf) for an example

Comment: Is it possible with the columns to hide one specific column? Because my customer wants to hide some metadates from time to time, and it would be a big disadvantage if he isn't possible to do so.
E.g: I've got the metadates "Year", "Customer" and "Ordernumber". I only want to display 2 of them - is it possible to play with the "rendered" value of the columns to just show 2?
Because I don't want to mess around with the metadates inside of my file, in the meaning of creating a secondList inside of each file, which shows just the metaDates that should be shown.

Comment: @TsukiShimizu, with a little tweaking, I'm sure you can sort that bit out :). All that `<p:columns/>` takes is a list to build the columns from. So restrict what makes it into that list and problem solved

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have this code:

```
<p:dataList id="fileList" var="f" value="#{reader.files}">
    <p:dataTable value="#{f.listItems}" var="meta1">
        <p:column>#{meta1.value}</p:column>
        <p:columns value="#{meta1.listItems}">...</p:columns>
    </p:dataTable>
</p:dataList>
```

Dynamic columns in nested dataTable are not generated: it seems p:columns cannot refer var like "f" and "meta1".
I can understand "meta1" is not visible, because it's producing header's table, but I really can't understand why "f" is not visible at that time.

Any idea? Thanks.